# Some Domain Users folder sync pulls everyone's files

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, activesync

Two of my domain users are acting weird. One workstation is a XP and another Windows 7 Pro connecting to a SBS2003 server.

When they login, it syncs the whole "Users" folder that holds every users' individual documents in the domain. This just started happening yesterday. The only thing that was changed was last friday I set up folder redirection for Application Data, Start Menu, and Desktop. Upon logging out Friday, it didn't sync those folder, and logging in Monday it gave them a blank desktop and blank start menu. I had some stations that couldn't even log in, so I removed this rule. However, it's still acting up.

The sync structure is like this:

> \servername\Users\%username%

It should just sync the \%username%\documents folder. It is syncing anyones folder under \Users\

It should be noted that the login takes a long time - a couple of hours. The solution for fixing one of my users, was to remove their account, delete their folders, and then add them back. However - if there's an easier fix I don't want to have to do this to every user that needs it.

Comment: The only solution I've found so far was to remove the user, remove the computer from the domain and then add both back. It's not pretty but it's the only thing that's working. If someone has an answer out there let us know incase someone else has the issue, it's too late for me to try it though. I'm just going to upgrade the server to 2010.